# New tag completer: info for tag links to tagged questions page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

## Steps to reproduce

1. begin to ask a question
2. begin to type a tag
3. hover over one of the matches
4. click **info**

## Expected

**Information** for the tag (ideally in a separate tab or window).

Example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info

## Actual

Tagged **questions**.

Example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion

## Demonstration of the bug

Movie at http://www.wuala.com/%23%23Apple-support/members/grahamperrin/2011/08/09/b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed; we'll be changing this later today!

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response :-) I'll apply a tick after the fix is confirmed.