# Accessing extended tag info is almost impossible

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tags, tag-wiki

The new tag popup makes it easy to watch or ignore particular tags and shows the tag info excerpt. Here's one on EL&U:

[image: Single-word-requests tag excerpt]

However, the [full tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) contains a lot more information which helps users. Getting at that information is not obvious: you need to click the *View tag* link which provides a [list of questions and an abbreviated excerpt](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), and then click the *Learn more...* link.

The old tag pop-up used to include a link to the full tag info, and it appears that this was implemented as a result of a [request in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101524/new-tag-completer-info-for-tag-links-to-tagged-questions-page) which changed behaviour which was remarkably similar to what happens now.

Here's [an example I found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256488/184638) to give the idea. The *Info* link showed the full tag info.

[image]

**The current behaviour is a regression, breaking something which was previously fixed.**

Could *View tag* in the new popup be changed to *Other questions* and a new *More info* link be included which gives easier access to the full tag info? Perhaps something like this...

[image: Proposed alternative]

Comment: Agree, but as far as I can see, in the new UX there's simply no proper place for "info" link. Not expert though, so hopefully UX expert can find such a place.

Comment: If anything that link should not be titled *info* but *read more ...* and I agree that it should be reintroduced on the tag popup

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Restore previous variant of tag popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313909/restore-previous-variant-of-tag-popup) – but I think this very post is more clear so maybe we need to close the other way around.

Comment: @rene I thought one moderator or another must have asked about this already, but I couldn't find it. As a mod myself, linking to the page in a comment is still a possibility, but I would really like users to find it for themselves.

Comment: There's a userscript that adds this functionality: https://stackapps.com/questions/8054/improved-tag-popup

Comment: Unfortunately userscripts don't help those who don't know about them, in particular first-time users who actually need the extended tag info.

Comment: It's a little disappointing that despite the "bug" tag, and being obviously a regression error, no-one from SE has reacted in nearly a year.

Comment: I'm not sure its an error, but its certainly something worth relooking

Comment: Heads up that this is on our list to revisit. Going to look into this with our UX team and see what we can do to address.

Comment: @JonChan why not [tag:status-review] then?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask We've been using status-review for items that get raised to us, but once we actually finish triaging them, we want to indicate it's in the plan for us to address, just not in the short term (also why it's not status-planned and status-deferred instead). We're still experimenting with some of this.

Comment: @JonChan While it's buoying that the issue has at long last been recognised, it **is** a regression error, a bug, objectively harmful to the user experience (especially for new users), and easy to fix. It's even more disappointing that it won't be fixed quickly and is being deliberately pushed even further on to the back burner.

Comment: I'm afraid I agree with Andrew, bitter experience proves that bugs/requests in status deferred just never get fixed. Maybe one or two ever. :/

Comment: @JonChan This has now been "status-deferred" for 18 months. Any news?

Comment: @JonChan And now more than six months after that...

Comment: lol, the "deferred" usually means "Thanks, but it's not going to happen" just without outright rejecting it due to being polite. I don't think I've ever seen a bug/feature marked as deferred being done. Not once.