# Please add a link to the tag wiki on the tag popup

Tags: feature-request, tags, popups

My **primary** reason for hovering a tag is to learn more about the tag. But when you hover a tag, that isn't one of the options on the popup. It has a link to questions tagged with that tag (with very misleading text), and buttons for following the tag or ignoring it, but not for going to the tag wiki to learn more about it. Before the redesign, the popup had an "info" link which I used all the time.

Two things which I believe fit within one FR:

1. Change the text of the current link to questions tagged with that tag. The current text is "View tag" which is odd, since it takes you to a list of questions, not the tag wiki.
2. Add a link to the tag wiki.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen this mentioned before but can't find it right now. Maybe it was on one of the answers on the design feedback questions.

Comment: this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314150/158100