# Change "View tag" to "View tag info" in tag tooltip

Tags: feature-request, tags, tooltips

In the tooltip of any tag below the question you can see a link "View tag" in the end of text that refers to the list of questions that have that tag. In the same time you can just click on the tag itself to open the same page. E.g.:

> [image: tag tooltip]

I suggest changing the text "View tag" to "View tag info" (and related link to the tag info page). E.g. for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag change it from:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion

to

https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info

This will add one more easy way to reach the tag info page (now you're able to navigate to only from "questions tagged" page via "Learn more" link):

> [image: Questions tagged]

save an extra click, reduce link duplication and would be more expected continuation to users that are looking for the detailed tag info after they read a short excerpt about the tag in tooltip.

Instead of "View tag info" there may be other sentences like "Learn more..." or something with obvious meaning that the link refers to the detailed tag info.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I'm not the only one. Getting to the tag info page is too difficult and confusing.

Comment: minimum that should be changed to "vue tag questions" but i vote to "vue tag info". imho

Comment: Related: [Accessing extended tag info is almost impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314150/289905).

Comment: Love this idea.  Not only would the text be more accurate, but I think it would be easier for new users too.

Comment: Related: [Be proud of tag wikis!](/q/279450/289905).