# Remove "View tag" link from the tag tooltip

Tags: feature-request, tags, popups

Since the old one [related feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353365/339911) is not implemented yet, I would like to ask for an alternative.

The list of question with a tag can be obtained by clicking on the tag itself, so there's no need to have additional link in the tooltip. Should it be removed at all to avoid overloading the UI?

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

If I just want to view the tag's questions I'll click it right away.

However, if I want to read about the tag, I read the excerpt, then if I want to read more I prefer not to go back, and having the link *after* the text makes lots of sense. I don't want it removed.

It's true that changing the link to directly show the info is better (I've upvoted the other FR), however until then, the info is just one click away.

Comment: The text on tag popup is very short, you don't have to move a mouse cursor (if you have the mouse) over text while reading. Moreover, you can accidentally close the popup by moving the cursor outside the popup's edges.

Comment: I mean the link appears to be natural after the text, but maybe it's just because I'm used to it being there, so wonder what new users will think of this.