# Please revert the line-height change!

Tags: bug, design, usability, accessibility

Just checking how many people feel similar. At least for me, the increased space between lines makes it a nightmare to read. My eyes lack guidance and just feel somehow lost with so much white space.

This change also breaks posts that use Unicode box-drawing characters, as pointed out in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353539/377214).

Details and reason given for the change:

> Our line spacing is ~1.6.
>
> W3C writes the following: "Many people with cognitive disabilities have trouble tracking lines of text when a block of text is single spaced. Providing spacing between 1.5 to 2 allows them to start a new line more easily once they have finished the previous one."
>
> We prefer more spacing between our lines for better readability. I think there are possible refinements between block level elements though, and plan on further refinement to header spacing now that this is in production. [via comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting#comment1181456_353529)

Comment: Also reported here: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353529/289905). Unfortunately marked as [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Here's my take on it: [Request for a possibility to adjust the spacing between lines for those with poor eyesight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353536/request-for-a-possibility-to-adjust-the-spacing-between-lines-for-those-with-poo). It may be closed as a duplicate, but it's not just that I don't **like** the new format. I can hardly read code anymore ...

Comment: I retract my comment on it being Stylus, @ChristianRau . There really is a bigger gap in the code blocks! Had to use my phone to get an old cached version, but you can see it in [old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz2yX.png) vs [new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kiOf.png).

Comment: @Larnu Another comparison on desktop: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353536/289905#comment1181514_353536

Comment: The change to larger linespace intervals literally slows me down on reading about two times. Unbelievable design choice.

Comment: It's not just line height. Something else has changed as well. I always format my code to avoid horizontal scrollbars in blocks of code. I have noticed they now appear if the number of characters on a line is near the right edge but is still completely visible.

Comment: @user289905 [tag:status-bydesign] or not, there's a first time for everything.  This could be the first time it's subject to change (revert).  Correct me if I'm wrong :D

Comment: @Ollie They obviously don't care about community opinion, so I doubt it will change anything. Might also get closed as a duplicate if you don't add any new aspects. But if you still go for it, I'll definitely upvote ;)

Comment: @Ollie I get that they need to take some decisions that doesn't fit everyone but this particular change seems to have upset _a lot_ of people. They _did_ set the `line-height` in code boxes back to _almost_ what it was, so at least they did listen for awhile. Perhaps a feature request to be able to select between a few pre-set modes would survive the dupe votes. It's not a request for a total reversal and it wouldn't have the kind of freedom I requested in my feature request so it'd be somewhere in between.

Comment: This was asked over a month ago, still hasn't been fixed...What now?

Comment: @Ollie Install the script/addon, accept that SE designers suck and move on with your life, I guess.

Comment: @MaxD Yeah...I don't think that SE's designers suck, it's just the decisions do...but they're their decisions.

Comment: @Ollie It's not who we are underneath, but what we do that defines us... :)

Comment: I thought we had firmly established there was no reason in any relevant guidelines to increase the line spacing. Why is this not reverted yet?

Comment: @einpoklum Cause SE designers. I'll upvote anything that brings up this issue again, but they've had their chances so I highly doubt it's gonna change anything, and I also have my userscript, so I'm not really motivated to make the effort.

Comment: @einpoklum If you want to make a new post, go for it, I'll upvote ;)

Comment: I'm wondering how you (the OP) and other people feel about the line-height change now. I was also against the change at first but my eyes have since adjusted to the change and it seems rather normal now.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I still prefer the `1.3` line-height.  I've had the userscript on for a while, so I can still compare the two, and I still like the old one better

Comment: @KodosJohnson I have had the user script on all the time, so I couldn't possibly have gotten used to it. I still think the change is objectively bad typography (just look at literally any book/magazine/etc.) and the least SE could have done was giving us an option. But, yeah, they didn't, and fortunately the script works perfectly 100% of the time, so it's whatever.

Comment: @CaveJohnson: I have a user-script for it, but not on all the computers on which I visit SE sites. So, I've got somewhat used to it, but I still like the old format better.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The new line-height makes it hard to mentally separate *paragraphs*. It's difficult to tell from a glance which lines belong to which paragraph, while the old line-height made this very easy to distinguish.

Anyways, let's do what we do best as programmers ;)

#### Revert Stack Exchange Formatting

- **[Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh)** *(customizable)*

  - *Update (May 2021): added option to **revert fonts***
- [Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/410067-revert-stackexchange-formatting) **|** *[(only line-height)](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Compact-Line-Height)*
- [Stylish theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/188588/revert-stackexchange-formatting) *(+ Stylus)* --| *[[Dark mode]](https://userstyles.org/styles/190977/revert-stackexchange-formatting-dark-mode)*

> **PLEASE UPDATE SCRIPTS!**: updated to fix new changes to code blocks ***(Sep 24, 2020)***

Mobile:

- [Limited solution: per-page click-activated JavaScript](https://github.com/Prid13/Revert-StackExchange-Formatting/blob/master/mobile/MOBILE%20INSTRUCTIONS.md) (iOS, Android)
- [Kiwi Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser) (Android) -- install the Chrome extension above *(not tested)*

#### Contribute:

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Prid13/Revert-StackExchange-Formatting) -- help me revert it faithfully!

Comment: Gonna switch the accept mark to this one to give it more visibility. I personally don't use Chrome, but for the majority of people it's probably the more accessible solution, and it also offers many additional features.

Comment: personally I don't trust extensions as I can't easily review their source code, like I can look at the javascript code of a userscript, so thanks for including both the userscript and the stylus userstyle for non-Chrome users

Comment: Is there an alternative for mobile (specifically Chrome in iOS)? I can't find any

Comment: the old community members were massively leaving the platform, even with the previous formatting. this new crappy one, might apparently happen to be the last nail into SO's casket

Comment: @mangusta Where could you leave to though? The only other site I can think of is quora, and I don't like it at all.

Comment: @hkotsubo: after researching extensively, the closest alternative in iOS is to use one-click **Javascript Bookmarklets** that run on a *per-page* basis -- you'll have to activate it manually per page load, unfortunately. I've included full mobile instructions in the post :) For lazy people: https://github.com/Prid13/Revert-StackExchange-Formatting/blob/master/mobile/MOBILE%20INSTRUCTIONS.md

Comment: Okay. It's good that there's at least a possibility of reverting it back. What would be even better, though, is to not break it in the first place.

Comment: @Prid BTW, in my phone I've added one more rule to add yellow background to blockquotes: `.s-prose blockquote { background: var(--yellow-050) !important }`

Comment: Can you fix the misspellings, here and on GitHub? It is "[Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)" (the last section - scroll down to "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"), Stack Overflow, [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), and [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) (***not*** StackExchange, StackOverflow, GreaseMonkey, Javascript, and Github).

Comment: @hkotsubo: awesome! I thought about adding yellow blockquotes as one of the scripts for mobile, but decided against it. Glad to know you solved it yourself :)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q: with all due respect, **StackExchange** is less mentally straining than Stack Exchange, and better denotes a *single* idea. That unneeded "horizontal line height" in between is ***exactly*** the problem this post is trying to solve, ironically. StackExchange should be an expected misnomer as what most visitors frequently see is the *logo* and the URL, which do a poor job at conveying the space. I'll accept the guidelines of this site, but I'm not changing it on Github.

Comment: @Prid: I don't think the spacing/capitalization "errors" matter too much either way, to be honest. Neither version of each name is particularly easier or harder to parse for me than the other. It's just that the official names of each site/plugin/entity use a certain styling, so as long as one gets reasonably close to that, it's fine.

Answer (score 60):

*This probably shouldn't be an answer, but I can't think of where else it should go.*

Aaron has [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting#comment1181456_353529) on the linked question that the line-height is ~1.6.

I maintain that the line-height needs to be tailored to the font in use and the size of that font in normal text. A blanket ratio is not enough; more finesse is required.

Most users will, I guess, use Arial. Arial is a good workhorse with a fairly-large x-height but generally narrow letters. It's the narrow, fairly large letters which make the line-spacing too wide. For posterity, here's a screenshot of the current arrangement:

[image: Line-height ratio 1.6]

A line-height ratio of 1.6 does work with other fonts and other source material. Here's a blog I maintain which uses Calluna Sans. That's a wider font. The font size is set as "1em", so it's decided by the browser, and you can see that the letter-height (and the x-height) are quite similar to Arial here with the default browser settings. But it's quite a bit wider, and the stroke weight is heavier. The source material is different, too; this is a text from a Catholic homily. A slightly more densely-argued text may well benefit from a greater line-spacing; and it's reasonable for such a site to look pretty too. However I would argue that for the vast majority of posts in SE, it's not needed.

[image: Line-height ratio 1.6 with Calluna Sans]

(The line length in the [blog](https://eastbourneordinariate.org.uk/archives/4189) is longer than that, but SE does odd things to wide images)

Stack Exchange posts are, for the most part, **not works of art.** They are factual posts where the content needs to be read easily, without worrying about how each line relates to the next. It's perfectly possible to see where paragraph breaks happen in this post, but the spacing — when combined with the font choice and possibly the line length — makes it difficult to relate lines together when reading, and that must be the prime objective.

The line-spacing doesn't even need to be whatever it was. I can't actually find that now, but I suspect it was the 1.30769231 which still appears in the stylesheet. That could be widened (although it's such a low priority when there are [far more important things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314150/184638) for SE to be working on); I would suggest 1.45 is sufficient for Arial. Other fonts like Georgia on [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and Palatino on [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) will probably need different values.

[image: Line-height ratio 1.45]

Comment: Ironic that even the webpage where they got the 1.6 from is perfectly readable, just our dear SE obviously has to be different... https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html

Comment: @MaxD Yes, that page is set for `line-height: 1.5;` which is within their own guidelines. I think I'd like to see **how** the W3C came up with those figures though. It's quite likely that the range they suggest is down to font considerations such as I give here.

Comment: Also interesting to see how they themselves are at the very bottom of their own range instead of somewhere in the middle like you'd expect. Maaaaybe because line-heights that big aren't actually that good.

Comment: The line-height was originally exactly [1.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9KMH.png), if I’m interpreting the CSS rules correctly.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/text-spacing.html > There's something there under 'related resources' that links to an entire, whole, study? Maybe that's where they got the figures from?

Comment: @AndrewLeach On that page he `line-height` for `body` is `1.5`, but for `p` and `td` it's `1.4`.

Answer (score 55):

I hope this gets reverted, but in the meantime, we can browse with the old line height of 1.3 with [this mini userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Compact-Line-Height) I wrote. Screenshot:

[image]

You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

Comment: @MaxD Once you install Tampermonkey (or another userscript manager), click the link to the userscript, then click the "raw" button on GitHub (above the code on the right side). Tampermonkey should then prompt you to install the script.

Comment: [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a user styles extension like [Stylus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_(browser_extension)), this is equivalent to `.s-prose { line-height: 1.3; }` (with or without linebreaks, of course). I ended up reducing both the line height and the margin-bottom of paragraphs.

Comment: For those without userscipt but who are using uBlock-Origin you can style elements with `element:style(details)` syntax. So all you need is add *custom filter* like `stackoverflow.com##.s-prose:style(line-height: 1.3 !important;)`. This can be done by picking at `stackoverflow.com` eye-dropper icon (selector tool in uBlock), select anything and replace selection text with `##.s-prose:style(line-height: 1.3 !important;)`.

Comment: You should add the style directly into the post as a code block for Stylus users - no need for extra userscript boilerplate if you have a dedicated extension for styles. (also I realize a userstyle is a convenient way to add all the SE/SO/SU, etc sites as matching rules but still)

Comment: @CertainPerformance You don't happen to know what the old background-color was? The new color hurts my eyes...

Comment: @TedLyngmo Old: #EFF0F1 New: #F6F6F6 see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353550

Comment: @CertainPerformance Now that they also changed paragraph spacing, could you, please, revert it as well? It looks horrible with old "normal" line height.

Comment: @valsaysReinstateMonica seems he already updated it 20 minutes ago without mentioning.

Comment: I made a **Chrome extension** for even more simplicity: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh

Comment: @user289905 Tampermonkey works fine on Firefox, too. This is my current setting.

Comment: Could you tweak the numbers a bit to account for yesterday's font change? At least to me, the old line height feels a bit too tight now compared to before, but the SE standard is still too wide.

Answer (score 48):

**Edit 2020-09-09:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It is quite common to use things like line drawing characters in illustrations. With the new line height on code blocks, this looks even worse than before.

#### Real-life examples

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61436303/5306507)

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│1 1│1 2│1 3│
├───┼───┼───┤
│2 1│2 2│2 3│
├───┼───┼───┤
│3 1│3 2│3 3│
└───┴───┴───┘
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63516205/5306507):

```
┌→────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ │
│ │0│ │1│ │2│ │3│ │4│ │5│ │6│ │7│ │8│ │9│ │
│ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ │
└∊────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

From [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101484/43319):

```
 ┌─┴─┐          
×/ ┌─┼───┐      
   ⊢ ÷ ┌─┼──┐  
      +/ - +⍨
```

From [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83587/43319):

```
    ┌──────┴──────┐
 ┌──┼────┐     ┌──┼──┐
┌┴┐┌┴┐┌──┴──┐ ┌┴┐┌┴┐┌┴┐
│⊢││~││∘.× ⍨│ │≢││↓││⍳│
└─┘└─┘└─────┘ └─┘└─┘└─┘
```

Comment: I do believe that real tables are actually on the roadmap though? (Your point still stands, large amounts of old posts that already use semigraphical tables notwithstanding)

Comment: @JohnDvorak - Even if so, how many hundreds of thousands of answers already do the above?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov you can't use mathjax in most of sites.

Comment: This doesn't look completed to me....

Comment: @Luuklag How so? I'd prefer 1.15 but with the new value it is at least readable.

Comment: Horizontal allignment is faaaaaaar off.

Comment: @Luuklag That's due to the font stack. [SE doesn't care](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17549/43319).

Answer (score 27):

There was probably no problem with the previous UI. Forgive me if there was. But if there was, keep it as an option that one can choose. Even better, keep two tabs, one for the previous, and one experimental. People might want to give feedbacks on experimental UIs. By the `experimental tab`, I mean a `Theme` tab. Users may choose one already made or customise one on their own.

By default, I would prefer the previous UI. It's looking just odd today!

> Edit: The text here as it appears now in mobile devices resembles the one in desktop devices. I mean the colour was sort of yellowish earlier in mobile devices. I hated this change most.

Comment: While this would be nice, it's an astronomical amount of work. Better would be to not make stylistic changes to underlying infrastructure on a whim in the first place.

Comment: I think that if there had to be more than one version for every UI change, things would be a horrible mess now.

Comment: Well, the idea was about `themes`. Some of us would prefer the previous one. Whoever doesn't like it may go to the proposed `experimental tab`, choose one that he/she likes most. Nothing else. It would just change the appearance.

Comment: This is what Wikipedia did, for example. You can still use the original themes if you want.

Answer (score 25):

To quote [@hkotsubo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change/353633#comment1181693_353561):

> Lots of people are saying it's harder to read. You should at least take this into
> consideration before saying you're done talking about it.

I totally agree.  It's not only on my laptop, it's worse on mobile too.  Although I don't use my mobile very often, I use it enough to make it a problem.  From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change/353561#comment1181673_353561) comment:

> That's not even just for people with cognitive disabilities, who struggle more than usual. It is true of everyone. Stop attacking the research angle while presenting nothing of your own. We're done talking about this.

It's *not* true for everyone, not for me anyway.

The feedback you're getting about this seems pretty negative.  Please, revert to `1.3`, and don't fix it if it isn't broken.  If [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change) [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353529/798831) posts are anything to tell by, the old way was better.

I won't deny there are exceptions, but the vast majority of us are saying it is not a good change.  If reverting it is not possible, or just isn't going to happen, then adding options in user preferences still seems like a good idea, hard work or not.

---

**UPDATE:**

Sixteen days have now passed since Aaron Shekey posted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353561/798831) answer with the update saying the proposed line-height of `1.6` had been adjusted to `1.5`, and we haven't received a reply to our many questions since.  Is Stack Exchange going to even consider reverting the changes, or adding options in user preferences?  Or is the change just going to endure, like the one about [the blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/please-revert-the-quote-background-from-white-to-yellow)?  Resourceful @Prid made another extension to revert the changes on that, too.

Extensions, userscripts, and various other "Band-aids" are all very well, but making tons of people use multiple third-party resources to revert the various poor design choices made by Stack Exchange is...not great.

I would also like to know why the larger line-height was deemed favorable, and why no user testing was performed (and if there was, we haven't heard about it)?  A line-height of `1.5` might be good for some, but it is *not* for all.  To quote @ResistanceIsFutile, "*catering for accessibility means catering for everyone, not just some.*"

I don't think giving us control over something as simple as line-spacing, or quote-background color, is a big deal to ask for.

Comment: Not responding or acting on said feedback isn't the same as not listening. Would them making a post stating that they hear our feedback but believe they're decision better serves the community change anything? They've already stated their reasoning for making the change, I don't see how them responding while not making further changes would be fruitful for anyone.

Comment: I mean, you're again assuming they don't know that a percentage of their community don't like the change. Offering this up as a choice has it's own problems, such as effectively multiplying the amount of testing needed to make sure a change doesn't break things.

Comment: Starting from a position of "They don't know", "They're not listening", or "They're ignoring us" pretty much precludes receiving no response. You're not coming from a position of willingness to listen, so why should they respond? They've clearly presented their reasoning, they budged on the original change to bring it to something at least better than what they started with, why not address their reasoning directly rather than just claiming they're failing their community?

Answer (score 22):

**Yes, I agree.** Please revert the line height back to 1.3! The [adjustment to 1.5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353561/674989) is not enough.

The lines are still harder to read IMHO.

Answer (score 21):

[Prid said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353605/276027)

> The new line-height makes it hard to mentally separate paragraphs.

I'd like to add that for me, the new spacing makes it very hard to tie even the same sentence together as I try to go from one line to the next.

It's so disconcerting and something I've never experienced before, but it makes me give up halfway down a paragraph because I've lost the thread of what was being said. I go back a couple of times to try to re-read, but it seems to make it considerably more effort.
As someone who's never had any reading difficulty since infant school 55 years ago, I find this particularly odd.
If this is some kind of medical condition It's not one I've ever noticed before.

This is a [link to a BBC News site page](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-53954642) which has similar wide spacing, but using a larger, slightly more solid font. I don't have the same difficulty with this. I have no real idea what technically differentiates one from the other - nor any clue how to look up what line spacing or font it uses.
[You have to bear in mind that, though Stack Overflow might be populated by people well-versed in or at least familiar with this type of work, the rest of us across Stack Exchange are just 'users'.]

There seems to be some knockback from mods/developers here who are insisting 'research shows bigger lines are better'.
Empirically, this doesn't appear to apply to everyone.
It seems someone read a research paper and the rest of us must suffer the consequences.

One additional factor that just ocurred to me is that Windows & Mac users are seeing rather different things. Ask Different used to use a Mac-specific font which was lovely to read - unfortunately that was removed a couple of years ago, leaving us with the poor alternative that SE now uses globally.

Screenshots of my earlier paragraph, first on Mac Safari

[image]

then on Windows Microsoft Edge

[image]

<sup>Click through to get these at 'life size' for better comparison.</sup>

So, by my own personal opinion, it doesn't look quite so bad on Windows as it does on Mac. There is a slightly better balance between font size & spacing.
This makes me think it was only ever checked on one platform.

Answer (score 20):

I want to draw readers' attention the fact that **the W3C does *not* actually recommend setting the line height to 1.5 or higher**.

The relevant recommendations seem to be WCAG criteria 1.4.12 (Text Spacing) and 1.4.8 (Visual Presentation).

Criterion [1.4.12](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#text-spacing) regarding text spacing reads (emphasis mine):

> In content implemented using markup languages that support the following text style properties, no loss of content or functionality occurs by setting all of the following and by changing no other style property:
>
> - Line height (line spacing) to at least 1.5 times the font size;
> - (etc.)

So this isn't a requirement, or a recommendation, for the line height setting - it's a requirement that *if* the lines are set to be more spaced-out, the site/webpage not become unusable or dysfunctional, and no content becomes invisible/inaccessible.

The W3C document entitled ["Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.12: Text Spacing"](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/text-spacing.html) reiterates this (emphasis mine):

> The intent of this Success Criterion (SC) is to ensure that people **can override** author specified text spacing to improve their reading experience.

The recommendation is to support overriding of settings to cater to the needs of some readers - *not* to change the default settings.

[WCAG criterion 1.4.8](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#visual-presentation) regarding Visual presentation reads:

> For the visual presentation of blocks of text, a **mechanism is available to achieve** the following: (Level AAA)
>
> ... snip ...
>
> Line spacing (leading) is at least space-and-a-half within paragraphs, and paragraph spacing is at least 1.5 times larger than the line spacing.

So, not the default, but achieveability through some mechanism.

@MaxD linked to a "techniques" document regarding criterion 1.4.8 which [mentions](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html) the importance of providing line spacing between 1.5 and 2, but:

- That document is not the official WCAG.
- "Providing" doesn't mean "having that be the default". The actual WCAG clarifies that the intent is providing the *mechanism* for making that setting. For example, a site-level per-user setting to that effect.
- Criterion 1.4.8 regards AAA-level conformance. That level is not intended (according to the WCAG document itself) for general use, but for more accessibility-specialized sites.

<sub>Due disclosure: I have posted this as a reply on [this related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/196834) as well.</sub>

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html), on the other hand: "Many people with cognitive disabilities have trouble tracking lines of text when a block of text is single spaced. Providing spacing between 1.5 to 2 allows them to start a new line more easily once they have finished the previous one."

Comment: @MaxD: See edit.

Comment: I'm having some trouble interpreting all these convoluted wordings. Maybe because I'm neither a native speaker nor have much of a webdesign background. So you're saying the 1.5-2 recommendation is ONLY aimed at sites that explicitly focus on special needs users? And that SE staff just copied the number without properly understanding its intended meaning?

Comment: @MaxD: It is actually slightly confusing, because 1.4.8 is level AAA while 1.4.12, with about the same recommendation, is AA level. But _none_ of them say a site should have 1.5-2x spacing by default for everyone. The assumption is that there is a _mechanism for enabling more spacing.

Comment: Huh.  If W3C's recommendation is based on the research(?) and came out to *less* than 1.5, then I'm curious as to why we went to 1.6, then back to 1.5.

Comment: @Ollie: But what happened on SE is not the W3C's recommendation anyway, so, in particular, it is not the recommendation of the underlying research.

Answer (score 14):

I’ve split the difference between the original `1.3` line-height and the proposed `1.6` line-height. We’re now at `1.5`, with additional refinements to spacing between elements. I’ve also reduced line height within code blocks back to near the original value.

### Update

It took me longer than I wanted, but I’ve got some updates for you on our `s-prose` component. You can see the [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/538) with my thinking over at our design system’s repo. It does the following:

1. Spreads `s-prose` headers out from paragraphs for better grouping.
2. Tightens up `s-prose` spacing between paragraphs a bit, and made sure spacing under headings are more consistent.
3. Replaces all `s-prose` margins internal to the component with a CSS variable `var(--s-prose-spacing)` so our users can more easily tinker with it in their browsers and user scripts.
4. Kills trailing margins in `s-prose`

You can see [some examples](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/prose/#minimal) of content at our Stacks documentation.

Comment: Why not simply rollback to the original everywhere (or  put this as an option in user preferences, so each one chooses whatever they want)? I think 1.5 it's still too much, specially - but not only - in mobile

Comment: @Aaron, it would be better if you could now change it back to `1.3` or even `1.2`.

Comment: Psychologists have been studying the effects of text presentation methods on comprehension and speed for decades, and the information presented by W3C is based on that research. Tons of research has repeatedly concluded that information from surrounding lines of text can interfere with reading speed and efficiency, suggesting additional spacing between lines of text is valuable. That's not even just for people with cognitive disabilities, who struggle more than usual. It is true of everyone. Stop attacking the research angle while presenting nothing of your own. We're done talking about this.

Comment: Lots of people are saying it's harder to read. You should at least take this into consideration before saying you're done talking about it...

Comment: @hkotsubo We're listening to the feedback we're getting about it. We are not listening to people who are simply stating "the research is nonsense" because that is not constructive to any discussion here. (The comments doing so have been deleted here, but my comment remains to deter people continuing to bash research instead of offering constructive opinions.)

Comment: @animuson can you link to the supporting studies? I'd like to read up on what kinds of reading material, at what font sizes, paragraph dimension ranges, reading duration and intermediately inserted content like code, quotes, illustrations they based their recommendations on. If https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html this is the source then I find it interesting that on the page it says 1.5 when the initially used value was greater, but maybe it's a different "w3c".

Comment: Whatever any research says or doesn't say, at the end of the day it's the users who are reading this site. And if 150+ users say a certain change makes it harder to read, while 0 say it makes it easier to read, then they probably might have a point? And the change probably might not be a good one? And should probably be reverted?

Comment: @MaxD Just so you know I've seen multiple people say they like the change better (even though the people who don't like the change definitely seem to be in the majority here) so 0 is definitely an exaggeration.

Comment: @animuson I don't want to argue against research. But if vast number of people is telling you that this change is bad for them, then it certainly carries some weight. I didn't have trouble reading old settings, but I do have trouble reading new one. It is especially bad for code. While small sections of text are equally readable with old and new settings, I have real trouble fast reading larger posts. This is detrimental for going through review queues and also for quickly browsing answers and finding solutions for problems. All that will now require more time than before.

Comment: @MaxD people who are unhappy are more likely to voice there opinion (loudly), then people who are content with something. So I think that is to some extent a flawed argument. Personally I think the comment section is easier to read, then the post body, and guess what line height the comments section has set ;). Also, old habits die hard.

Comment: @MaxD well, to state a positive feedback atleast, for me it’s easier to read on the mobile view, but I cant talk about the desktop experience if it’s horrible,  because Im stuck at the hospital atm, but on my small screen phone it’s clearly easier for me.

Comment: @animuson I don't want to attack any research, but I guess it's not "true for everyone": https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353588/401803 - just saying :-)

Comment: One other factor I would like to read up on in the aforementioned but not yet linked to research, is were the study participants previously used to reading content styled the same way for many years, like many of the frequent users of StackExchange. Something makes me think the "novelty" element was not accounted for. So it would probably be better to let all the existing users have a "legacy style" option while all the newly registered users could be harmlessly welcomed by a new style to which they are not used to.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has yet pointed out that "splitting the difference" would be 1.45, not 1.5.

Comment: @SteveBennett ...which coincidentally has been [mentioned before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353538/184638).

Comment: @Flounderer I don't know if you saw or if it helps, but note the follow up that "we're done talking about this" was only referring to a certain subset of comments bashing the research without bringing anything else to the table. [Please revert the line-height change!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1181696)

Comment: @animuson Look, this change was clearly based on a W3C recommendation, not on decades of research. The W3C is attempting to provide a one-size-fits-all recommendation, which may not be the right solution for Stack Exchange. Research is more nuanced than that. I'd be interested to see what the research says about readability in the context of technical writing, specifically. Speaking of research, has any user testing been performed before deploying this change site-wide?

Comment: @animuson right now the argument by SE is simply “because the W3C said so”. As long as as SE doesn’t actually cite the specific research, I don’t think it is unsurprising that people aren’t convinced by the “research”. You cannot make constructive arguments against research you’ve never seen.

Comment: I still think the best solution is to add options in user preferences, so everyone chooses whatever they think it's best, and as a bonus SE automatically gets stats about those preferences, which is some kind of "research", btw (I heard you like researches, so why not have one with your own users? Some researches say that's usually a good idea...)

Comment: @user1271772: "Is there anyone that likes the new line-spacing that you created (whether 1.6 or 1.5)?" Yes. At least a few people have said so. Rubiksmoose already said as much in response to MaxD claiming "0 [people] say it makes it easier to read" earlier in this exact comment thread. I get that some people don't like the change, but you don't need to use extreme hyperbole/ignore the existence of opposing perspectives in order to argue against the change.

Comment: @animuson "Stop attacking the research angle while presenting nothing of your own. We're done talking about this." I'm sorry if this has been written somewhere else, but I cannot find any linked research in the original post about this recent change [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting). Wouldn't it be good even if only for further reading to add some of the research that this change was based on, so users can not only enjoy it but also get educated?

Comment: This answer would probably be received better if it would explain more about why a larger line height was deemed favorable. It seems that a substantial amount of people like a smaller value better, so a good explanation why a larger value would actually be better might go a long way towards acceptance.

Comment: @user1306322 I find it interesting to note that even the W3C page you linked to, which advocates for 1.5 to 2.0 line spacing, uses 1.4 line spacing.

Comment: Almost 2 weeks has passed an not a single reply from SE (where's the mentioned "researches"? are you really listening to our feedback? Are we going to live with this readability issues forever?). It's a shame that once again they're ignoring community's feedback and keeping the changes, [just like they did with blockquotes](/q/344874/401803). I guess they're really "done talking about this"...

Comment: @hkotsubo I guess they really really are.

Comment: [Why hasn't this been reverted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change/353633#comment1188231_353525)  It's clear enough your community doesn't like it.

Comment: Yes, why _hasn't_ this been reverted? @Jeff: W3C does not advocate for that.