# Please remove the horizontal whitespace in the left part of code blocks

Tags: feature-request, design, code-formatting

With the [new post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting) there's extra **horizontal** whitespace at the left of **code blocks** (not to be confused with the [increased line height](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change)).

**Before** the new formatting:

[image]

**Now** (red circle shows the extra space):

[image]

I don't know if this extra space is intentional, but it is **annoying**. I keep thinking "there's unwanted space there, let's fix that code block".

It is also **confusing**, at least in some sites, such as [Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). In that site, code typically needs to be as short as possible, and  specialized programming languages are often used in which a space character can be much more meaningful than in normal languages. For example, in the images shown above, one would now think that the code has 5 bytes (not the claimed 4), with an initial space character.

The whitespace before the new formatting was tiny enough that it wasn't confused with an actual space character. Can we revert to that?

Comment: So many times now I've gone back to edit my answer because I thought embarrassingly left extra white space in. So I count out 4 spaces... and the space is still there 

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah, me too *makes wry face*.

Comment: Old version looks way too tight to me... :-/

Comment: @JoshGoebel [_Tight, tight, tight, yeah!_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLHLsbD9emc)