# Do bookmarks count as votes, in the timeline of a question?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks, timeline

In the "Show vote summaries" tab, in the timeline of [Please revert the line-height change!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change), I noticed that the daily vote summary included bookmarks:

[image]

Why are they there?  Do they count as part of the daily vote summary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, setting a bookmark (called Favorite earlier) is a Vote. As such it is stored in the Votes table with a Votetypeid of 5.

You can also find those in SEDE:

```
SELECT * FROM VoteTypes
```

[image]

The added value of having those Votes in SEDE as well is that you can list [which users bookmarked that question](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1292672). That is something the timeline will not tell you.

Comment: Wait, Spam is a vote? I thought it was a flag! How exactly do you vote Spam on a post, and how is that different from flagging as Spam?

Comment: @RobertColumbia not all votetypes are still used today. For example Close is not used anymore here. In SEDE there is  a PendingFlags table. I assume the realdeal has a Flags table by now. Bit that is guess work.