# Provide a magic link to the more detailed tag info page

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, magic-links

Currently, as a Sci-Fi moderator, if I want to send a new user to read up on how to use the <kbd>[story-dentification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)</kbd> tag in a comment, I have to manually link to `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info`.

This is because the magic link for tags, e.g. `[tag:story-identification]` currently goes to `questions/tagged/<tag-name>` i.e. `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification`. This is great in a lot of cases! Lets not change that!

But if you use the magic link in my case (trying to send a user to read up on the detailed info page) then you need to point the user to the 'learn more' page:

[image: screenshot of the 'questions tagged' page for javascript. The text 'Learn more' is scircled in red.]

Before they see this important info:

[image: screenshot of some of the advice from the JavaScript tag.]

And by then you might as well make a manual link.

Because of that, I'd like a way to easily magic-link new users to the more detailed page. Something like `[tag-info:story-identification]` or `[tag:story-identification/info]`.

For a list of all magic links, and where they work see: [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)

---

I'd like to note this will mostly help both new users who either aren't a) familiar with accessing the info page for tags, or b) need to read them as they aren't as familiar with how stack exchange sites works for some 'special' or easily misused tags. This is as well as making it easier for older users to quickly point new users to important information (yeah, I know not all new users will necessarily read that page. But more will if you directly link them to it.)

And I don't think it's just our site that would benefit. A tag like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) on [SO] has a lot of 'before you ask' type info in it... as do a bunch of tags on [english.se].

There is a related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314150/accessing-extended-tag-info-is-almost-impossible) asking to make this page more accessibly elsewhere, but I think these two questions complement each other rather than duplicate in anyway.